# App crashes when writing to SQLite Database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I have developed an app, however the User Registration seems to crash the app. I have checked everything but cannot find the cause, if anyone can assist.  My code is below.

**java class**

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

}

public void onSignupClick (View view)
{
    if (view.getId() == R.id.BsignUp)
    {
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFemail);
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFuname);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpass1);
        //EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpass2);

        String namestr = name.getText().toString();
        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.setName(namestr);
        c.setEmail(emailstr);
        c.setUname(unamestr);
        c.setPass(pass1str);

        helper.insertContact(c);

    }
  }
}
```

**xml layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src ="@drawable/saica"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFname" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Email Address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFemail" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFuname" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFpass1"
        android:password="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BsignUp"
        android:onClick="onSignupClick"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pooveshin.saica_sgb, PID: 10321
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.example.pooveshin.saica_sgb.SignUp.onSignupClick(SignUp.java:30)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `EditText` named `TFusername`, your actual EditText id is `TFname`. So it should be

```
EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFname);
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing what I couldn't see.